# Input box not showing in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am working in Visual Studio Code.

My app.component.html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

My app.component.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

My problem is that the input box is not showing in the browser http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing FormsModule import in your module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
        ProfileListComponent,
        ...
    ]
})
```

NgModel directive is part of FormsModule, thus the need to import it. You can read more about NgModel directive here.

for ex: follow link [angular form](http://embed.plnkr.co/hKCBa1RDob5H9i9x7ZhT)

Comment: Failed to compile.

C:/Users/Dell/my-first-app/src/app/app.module.ts (14,5): Cannot find name 'ProfileListComponent'.

Comment: @Boidurja ProfileListComponent is example of Shashi code so you don't need to add ProfileListComponent ... Add your Component and import FormsModule in your module file